# Como puedo verificar que la URL sea correcta?

Tags: jquery, html5, asp.net, razor

Estoy rompiendome la cabeza con esta situación y no se ni siquiera por dónde empezar.

Tengo una lista de `URLs` válidas para un `input`, digamos 10 `url` desde donde los usuarios pueden introducir links en un `input`, lo que busco es que si el usuario introduce un `link` de una `URL` que no está en esa lista, le salte un error y no le permita darle al botón de Ingresar sabiendo que el código solo debe validar lo que está entre `www` y el `.com` o `.net`, ya que después del `.com`  lo que sigue es del link y eso siempre variará.

Tengo el `HTML` realizado no lo publico porque realmente no he podido pasar de este punto.

Answer (score 2):

Usa la función [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) de  `javascript` para cuando obtengas  la url ("`www.urldeprueba.com`") pueda tenerla separada por partes usando como separador "**.**" y para acceder a cada parte lo haces con un `array` ( hago `urlSplit[0]` para acceder al primer texto separado).

Solo restaría a partir de ahí hacer las validaciones que creas conveniente. De ejemplo agregue la validación de que comience con **www** y de que el `string` que se separe  tenga tres partes como mínimo (un formato `www.prueba.com`) .

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 
</head>
<body>
<label>Url </label>
<input id="url" name="">
<label id="msg"></label>
<br>
<button onclick="ValidaUrl()"> Valida Url</button>
<script>
function ValidaUrl()
{
  var url =$("#url").val();
  var urlSplit = url.split(".");
  if(urlSplit.length > 2) // parametro que cambiaras segun sea la estrutura de tu url 
  {
    if(urlSplit[0] != "www")
    {
      $("#msg").text("Url Invalida");
      return;
    } else {
      $("#msg").text("Url Valida");
    }
    // aqui agrega las demas condiciones para validar tu url
  }
  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```